# Trying to trim/slice white spaces from Discord usernames

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Okay, so basically I tried doing this

```js
if(message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name.includes(message.author.username.replace(/^\s+/g, ' ') + message.author.discriminator))) return message.channel.send(`You already have an open ticket!`)

message.guild.createChannel(message.author.username.split(" ") + message.author.discriminator, {
    type: "text",
    permissionOverwrites: [{
        id: message.author.id,
        deny: [],
        allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGES"]
    }]
}).then(chn => {
    chn.overwritePermissions(message.guild.id, {
        "SEND_MESSAGES": false,
        "READ_MESSAGES": false
    })
}).then(chan=> {
    message.channel.send(`Successfully created a ticket!`)
})
```

But that didn't work, I'm probably really really wrong somewhere here, does anyone know how I can slice/trim the white spaces in a name so I can look for the ticket?

Comment: I think it's important to mention that using username and discriminator to uniquely identify someone is not best practice. Different numbers of spaces make a username unique, so you could have an account named `user name#1234` and another account named `user ​ name#1234` at the same time. Both could theoretically use your bot at the same time, and their names would be evaluated identically if you cut out spaces. For creating a channel, you might consider tying a user's "snowflake" ID to an incrementing channel count within your bot. This might get you the reliable result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all whitespace from a string, use this [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): **`/\s+/g`**

- `\s` matches any whitespace character (spaces, line breaks, other Unicode whitespaces).
- `+` matches one or more of the preceding token/group, matching and returning as much as possible (this is called being greedy).
- The `g` flag stands for **g**lobal, meaning each occurrence is matched.

```js
const str = 'sloth if ul#3802';

console.log(str);
console.log(str.replace(/\s+/g, '_'));
```

Putting this in action...

```js
// User.tag === User.username + User.discriminator
const cleanTag = message.author.tag.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,

But, I think I messed up somewhere:

```if(message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name.includes(message.author.tag.replace(/\s+/g, "_")))) return message.channel.send(`You already have an open ticket!`)

```

I believe this is wrong

Comment: Sidenote: The best I could figure out is using the Author's ID to create the channel name

Comment: It depends on how you originally created the channels. Replace the underscore in `replace()` with whatever character is used instead of a whitespace. Generating your own ticket IDs or using the author's ID is indeed a better option.

Comment: I've sliced off 14 characters from the ID itself so it doesn't take up space.
The code looks like this now:

```if(message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name.includes(message.author.id.slice(14)))) return message.channel.send(`You already have an open ticket!`)

    message.guild.createChannel(message.author.id.slice(14) + "-" + message.author.username, {```

Comment: If you wanted to get fancy with it, you could also map parts of the id to [English words](https://github.com/a-type/adjective-adjective-animal/tree/master/lib/lists) like GfyCat does. This might make for more memorable, user-friendly channel names to your users.

Comment: The best thing would be to actually make a database and add up +1 for every new ticket to be honest.